# requestvideoframecallback and video.onSeeked event firing order

Tags: google-chrome, web, safari, html5-video

I am trying to find if there are any specifications regarding the firing order of `requestvideoframecallback` and the `video.onSeeked event`.

All I could find is that requestvideoframecallback will fire after requestanimation frame.

Comment: **(1)** What problem does knowing the firing order solve? Maybe there is a better solution to the problem (_eg:_ is the main problem about some video synchronization issue?)... **(2)** Did you try any test in any browser? Did you make a basic code with a `<video>` tag and some event listeners (with console logging for results)? **(3)** How to re-create a situation where the firing order matters? Or in other words, how to know when one has reached the right answer for you (what is expected result)?